# Create Values based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel, dax

How to create a values based on 2 conditions on `DAX`

I want to create a value of 8 for each user and for each day.

So now if a user have 1 single event in 1 day the Value should be 8.

If a User have 5 events in a single day the value also should total 8, it can like the first event will be 8 and the rest will be null.

```
USER    DATE            EVENT       VALUE
-------------------------------------------
Dan     2016-01-01      Event 1 
------------------------------------------- 
Nat     2016-01-01      Event 1 
Nat     2016-01-01      Event 2 
Nat     2016-01-01      Event 3 
Nat     2016-01-01      Event 4 
Nat     2016-01-01      Event 5 
-------------------------------------------
```

Expected Result

> ```
> USER       DATE           EVENT          VALUE
> -------------------------------------------
> Dan       2016-01-01      Event 1         8
> -------------------------------------------   
> Nat       2016-01-01      Event 1         8
> Nat       2016-01-01      Event 2 
> Nat       2016-01-01      Event 3 
> Nat       2016-01-01      Event 4 
> Nat       2016-01-01      Event 5 
> -------------------------------------------
> ```

I am trying the query like

```
=IF([USER] & [DATE];8;0)
```

How to write this script on DAX or Excel !

Any one knows any solution to this problem !

Comment: It looks as if you could just put IF(C2="Event 1",8,"") in Excel but I'm sure it's not really that simple - e.g. are the events shown as times?

Comment: you have date where ther'arent event? or you don't have this info?